# Predict whether the customer gross sales for the next month category for a product and Territory based on customer’s historical monthly sales data

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I am new to R programming and I have to do some kinda POC(Proof of Concept) work at my workplace in which I have to predict the gross sales for the next months for customers based on product and Territory(Sales channel). Here's how my data looks [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hosTE.png)

the data is till March'2017 and both Product and Sales Channel are categorical and has levels 2. Also Sold_Customer is categorical with 66 levels. 
I have searched on internet a lot and came across "Forecasting in R" and other related stuff but all of that includes data in time series form but my data is not in this format neither I know how to use that because most of my columns are character type. If anyone can help me out and guide me how to approach for this particular problem, I would be really thankful to him/her.

Comment: You predict gross sales from what? Previous gross sales?  Does it has seasonality?

Comment: Actually this is the data I got and what is expected is that I need to predict the gross sales for the next month for all the customers based on product and sales_channel. This is required so that we can compare the gross sales of customers for a particular product and sales_channel for previous month. @user31264